# How to use multiple threads for zlib compression

Tags: multithreading, compression, zlib

I have a large chunk of data (around 2 GB) that needs to be compressed using zlib (deflate()). I am currently reading 500 kb of data at 1 go, compressing it and writing it to my output file.

With 1 thread, everything is fine. The data is compressed and I am able to write it and uncompress it back.

With 2 threads, the process hangs in deflate() call.

Here is the outline of the function that is called by my 2 zlib comp threads.

```
static z_stream z_str;

zlib_compress(...., bool last, bool first)
{

    if (first)
        deflateInit(&z_str, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

    if (last)
        flush = Z_FINISH;
    else
        flush = Z_SYNC_FLUSH;

....
....
    status = deflate(&z_str, flush);
...
...
    if (last)
        deflateEnd(&z_str);

}
```

As I understand, both the calls are referring to the same zstream while calling deflate(), which is resulting in undesired behaviour.

I tried to take z_str as a local variable and modified the code accordingly. But while uncompressing, it is assuming 512 as the total size of the file which is actually just the first chunk of data.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like your code only calls deflate() a single time for each call to zlib_compress().  Are you calling your zlib_compress function multiple times in each thread?  If so, then deflateInit() and deflateEnd should not be part of the zlib_compress() call; rather they should be done only at the beginning and the end of the processing sequence (for each thread)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I have removed most part of the code for simpler understanding. Yes I am currently calling them only once, but not per thread. I am calling deflateInit() while the first chunk(512 kb) of data is being compressed and deflateEnd() while the last piece of data(<=512 KB) is being compressed. For compression, both the threads refer to the same z stream and try to compress the data. While doing this, the process hangs in deflate() call.

Should I try calling them per thread? Also now I am wondering, whether it is really possible to compress with multiple threads or not?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks a lot. Could you post it as answer? I would like to accept it.

Comment: Okay, I have converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple threads compressing data simultaneously, as long as each thread has its own separate z_stream object. Each z_stream object should have deflateInit() called on it, then as many calls to deflate() as necessary, and then deflateEnd() called after all of the uncompressed data has been passed to deflate(). Using this technique, it would be straightforward to e.g. compress two different files at once.

However I suspect that what you are trying to do is speed up the compression of a single large file, no? In that case, you'll find that is not possible to do, at least not in the obvious way. The reason it's not possible is that the latter bytes of a deflated stream depend on the earlier bytes of that stream for their meaning -- which means that they cannot be generated until after all of the earlier bytes have been generated, which rules out generating the second half of the compressed file in parallel with the first half.

What you could do is generate two separate compressed files; one that is the compressed contents of the first half of the uncompressed file, and the other that is the compressed contents of the second half of the uncompressed file. That could be done in parallel since the two compressed streams would be fully independent of each other. Note that you would then need to write your own routine to uncompress those two files and concatenate the result back into a single uncompressed file again, since standard compression/decompression utilities would not be aware of this divide-and-conquer trick.

As pointed out by the original author of zlib (Adler), it is possible to compress large chunk of data in parallel as exemplified in pigz.  Essentially you need to supply 32K of uncompressed data proceeding a particular chunk.

```
==Chunk 1===
       -32K-====Chunk 2=======
                       --32K--====Chunk 3====
```

Then you can combine the compressed data.

Comment: No, you can speed up compression by a factor of _n_ with _n_ processors/cores.  That is what [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) does.  Each thread is provided with both the portion of the data to compress and the 32K of uncompressed data that precedes that portion.  That 32K is all it needs for compression context.  The compressed streams can all be generated in parallel and then combined.

Comment: Please either work in the comment from Mark Adler (preferred) or delete the answer, as it's in the most part wrong!

Comment: If @MarkAdler posts his comment as an answer, I'll delete my answer; I don't want to try to paraphrase him, but I also don't want to delete my answer since his comment is attached to it.

Answer (score 5):

> As I understand, both the calls are referring to the same zstream
>   while calling deflate(), which is resulting in undesired behaviour.

What did you expect to happen?

Each thread needs it's own `z_stream` structure to work with.  Two threads accessing the same `z_stream` at the same time makes no sense.

Comment: I expected the same to happen. I have mentioned that method just to explain my intention. I wanted an alternative to compress the same file in two multiple threads. I was thinking it was not possible in a conventional way and Jeremy has confirmed it in the comments.

Comment: How about you ask about what you actually want to know?  If you want to know how to speed up compression with multiple cores, then please ask that.  The last two paragraphs of Jeremy's answer are not correct.

Comment: I See. I am bad at framing simple questions. Will check about it pigz right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The solutions looks great. It is provided as a utility. I would like to use it with along with my source(Android). Is there a library version of pigz available?

Comment: No, there is not a library version.  It uses zlib, so you can look at the source code for pigz and use the same approaches, or adapt the pigz source to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am currently doing that. Please make a mention of it and edit the answer if its ok

Comment: Hi Mark, to combine checksum's I understand that I have to look into COMB() macro. But what about dictionary id? I am not able to get it from source. Could you please refer to a place in the source to look for? From my understanding a zlib compressed stream is as follows {uint8 cmf; uint8 flag; uint32 DICT,char data[COMP_SIZE], uint32 adler}. When combing two zlib compressed streams, how do i combine their respective DICT values?

Comment: You can't.  zlib streams that use different dictionaries cannot be combined.  It is rather unusual to see zlib streams that use dictionaries at all.  Where are these streams coming from?

Comment: Thanks Mark. After your comment, I read the RFC again, the DICT field in the flag is not set. So there is no dictionary. But I haven't had success yet. From the compressed stream, the last four bytes are adler value. So I am calling COMB() for each job with the last 4 bytes of my compressed stream. But unfortunately, if a work is having only 1 job, my logic is working fine. But when I am combining(using COMB() ) adler of two or more jobs and updating it, its not working. de-comp is failing. I tried adler32_comb() as well. Same result. I am not wrtng the adler of every job into the output file.

Comment: In my existing design, every job has a compressed data. It includes header and a trailer. SO for the first job I am updating the header + compressed data into the output file. For the subsequent jobs, I am updating only the compressed data(comp_buf+2(not copying header), comp_size - 6(2 bytes for header and 4 bytes for trailer)). When my work is getting finished, then I am updating the adler value(I keep calculating this value for every job like how I have described in my prev comment). DO you see any flaw in this approach. Thank you.

Comment: You need to write a new question, describing what you are trying to do, how you are doing it, and what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Could you please look at this new post and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794053/how-to-use-multiple-threads-for-zlib-compression-same-input-source

Comment: Since we are in big data era, if the pigz is elevated to a library, then it would be extremely popular among big data programmer.  Is there any hidden trap to prevent this from happening?  If not, I can give a try.

Comment: The only impediment, besides my time, is the interface. What would a user of a parallel compression library expect for how it would be used by the application programmer?

Comment: @MarkAdler thanks a lot.  I am looking at the pigz code.  Very well written with plenty of comments.  I am forced to apply the parallel to my big data project where I need to knock down hours of time.  Maybe you can add pseudo code to this answer to give people an overview (general layout).